# How to use count() function in a vector<struct> according to specific criteria

Tags: c++, vector, struct, count

I have a vector of type struct with some elements, and trying to count the number of occurrences of an element(value) in its corresponding column of the vector. I know how to count on a simple vector, e.g on `vector of type string`. But am stuck on `vector<struct>`. Any possible solution or suggestion?

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct my_struct
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<my_struct> my_vector(5);

  my_vector[0].first_name = "David";
  my_vector[0].last_name = "Andriw";

  my_vector[1].first_name = "Jhon";
  my_vector[1].last_name = "Monta";

  my_vector[2].first_name = "Jams";
  my_vector[2].last_name = "Ruth";

  my_vector[3].first_name = "David";
  my_vector[3].last_name = "AAA";

  my_vector[4].first_name = "Jhon";
  my_vector[4].last_name = "BBB";

  for(int i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++)
  {
      int my_count=count(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),my_vector[i].first_name);
      /*I need help to count the number of occerencess of each "First_name" in a vector
         For example:   First_Name:- David   COUNT:- 2 ...and so on for each first_names*/    
      std::cout << "First_Name: " << my_vector[i].first_name << "\tCOUNT: " << my_count << std::endl;
  }
 return 0;
}
```

but, the same code for a *vector of type string*,`std::vector<std::string>`  works properly. see below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> my_vector;
  my_vector.push_back("David");
  my_vector.push_back("Jhon");
  my_vector.push_back("Jams");
  my_vector.push_back("David");
  my_vector.push_back("Jhon");

  for(int i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++)
  {
      int my_count = count(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),my_vector[i]); //this works good
      std::cout << "First_Name: " << my_vector[i] << "\tCOUNT: " << my_count << std::endl;
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `std::count_if` with correct predicate:

```
int my_count = std::count_if(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),
    [&](const my_struct& s) {
        return s.first_name == my_vector[i].first_name;
    });
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VwB9ei)

The functor to replace lambda in C++03:

```
struct CompareFirstName
{
    explicit CompareFirstName(const std::string& s) : first_name(s) {}

    bool operator () (const my_struct& person) const
    {
        return person.first_name == first_name;
    }

    std::string first_name;
};
```

and then

```
int my_count = std::count_if(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),
                             CompareFirstName(my_vector[i].first_name));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/QknySG)

Comment: hello @jarod42, can you please guide me how to use  "std::count_if()".

Comment: I see the "Demo", but with some errors.  error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
and : expected primary-expression before ‘const’  . thanks. am using gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) 


'

Comment: As you don't have access to C++11, you have to do a functor instead of the lamdba.

Comment: That is Perfect solution!! Thanks.